# Reference message id when submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When users compose a message, how can I setup so that it references the new message_id created for the `conversation_id` inside the Messages table?

For example User A sends a new message to User B. Message_id 26 is created and the conversation_id will be 26.

show.html.erb:

```
<h4>Send Message To User</h4>
<p><%= link_to "Message Me", new_user_message_path(@user), :class => "button" %>
```

new.html.erb:

```
<%= f.text_field :conversation_id %>
```

controller:

```
  def index
    @messages = Message.scoped
    @message = Message.new
    if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = @user.sent_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
    elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox"
      @messages = @user.received_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
    #elsif params[:mailbox] == "archived"
     # @messages = @user.archived_messages
    end
    if params[:mailbox] == "unread"
    @messages = @user.unread_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
  end
  if params[:mailbox] == "trash"
    @messages = @user.deleted_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
  end
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
    @message.conversation_id = params[:conversation_id]
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.sender_id = @user.id
    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent"
      redirect_to user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox=>:inbox)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @new_message = Message.new
      @message = Message.find(params[:id])
      @message.readingmessage if @message.recipient == current_user
    end

  def reply
      @reply_message = Message.new
      @message = Message.new
      @message.conversation_id = params[:conversation_id]
  end


   def destroy
     @message = Message.find(params[:id])
     @message.destroy
     flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted message."
     redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
   end

  def delete_multiple
      if params[:delete]
        params[:delete].each { |id|
          @message = Message.find(id)
          @message.mark_message_deleted(@message.id,@user.id) unless @message.nil?
        }
        flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
      end
      redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
  end


  def update
      @message = Message.new
      if params[:reply_to]
        @reply_to = User.find_by_id(params[:reply_to])
        unless @reply_to.nil?
          @message.recipient_id = @reply_to.id
        end
      end
    end
```

Model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :subject, :conversation_id, :body, :parent_id, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :read_at,:sender_deleted,:recipient_deleted
    validates_presence_of :subject, :message => "Please enter message title"
    has_many :notifications, as: :event
    belongs_to :conversation, inverse_of: :messages
    belongs_to :user
  scope :unread, -> {where('read_at IS NULL')}
  scope :not_deleted_by_recipient, where('messages.recipient_deleted IS NULL OR messages.recipient_deleted = ?', false)
  scope :not_deleted_by_sender, where('messages.sender_deleted IS NULL OR messages.sender_deleted = ?', false)

    belongs_to :sender,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
    belongs_to :recipient,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'


    after_create :set_converstation_id

    def set_conversation_id
      update_column :conversation_id, id    
    end

    def reply
      new_message.reply_from_user_id = self.id #save the user id of original repost, to keep track of where it originally came from
  end

  def self.by_date
      order("created_at DESC")
    end

    # marks a message as deleted by either the sender or the recipient, which ever the user that was passed is.
    # When both sender and recipient marks it deleted, it is destroyed.
    def mark_message_deleted(id,user_id)
            self.sender_deleted = true if self.sender_id == user_id
            self.recipient_deleted = user_id if self.recipient_id == user_id
            (self.sender_deleted > 0 && self.recipient_deleted > 0) ? self.destroy : self.save!
            (self.sender_deleted != 0 && self.recipient_deleted != 0)
        end
    # Read message and if it is read by recipient then mark it is read
    def readingmessage
      self.read_at ||= Time.now
      save
    end

    # Based on if a message has been read by it's recipient returns true or false.
    def read?
        self.read_at.nil? ? false : true
    end

    def self.received_by(user)
       where(:recipient_id => user.id)
     end

     def self.not_recipient_deleted
       where("recipient_deleted = ?", false)
     end

     def self.sent_by(user)
        Message.where(:sender_id => user.id)
      end

      def next(same_recipient = true)
        collection = Message.where('id <> ? AND created_at > ?', self.id, self.created_at).order('created_at ASC')
        collection.where(recipient_id: self.recipient_id) if same_recipient
        collection.first
      end

      def previous(same_recipient = true)
        collection = Message.where('id <> ? AND created_at < ?', self.id, self.created_at).order('created_at DESC')
        collection.where(recipient_id: self.recipient_id) if same_recipient
        collection.first
      end
    end

    private
    def send_notification(message)
      message.notifications.create(user: message.recipient)
    end
```

Comment: how does user's B message reference which message (the id of user's A message) he is replying to?

Comment: The reply to part I understand how to do. The main issue is the new message. User A visits User B's profile. Clicks 'send message' and is taken to /users/2/messages/new. When the users fills out the form and clicks send it should generate a numerical `conversation_id`. My preference would be for the `conversation_id` to be the same as the new message id that was created. I understand how to reference the message conversation_id in a reply to message. I'm trying a few things out now and may have something soon hopefully.

Comment: Is conversation a separate model? How are they related?

Comment: @rlecaro2 It's part of the Messages model. There's a `conversation_id` column inside of the table. I am only looking to copy the new message_id being created to the conversation_id column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have separate models for conversations and messages, how will you discriminate between the creation of a message and the creation of a conversation?

You should have a Conversation Model that `has_many` messages and references both users.

Anyways, what you're asking is to have a `conversation_id` when creating a brand new  message (or conversation)?

You can do this in two ways:

1.- Change

```
@message.conversation_id = params[:conversation_id]
```

to

```
@message.conversation_id = @message.id
```

And in the view use a `hidden_field_tag` (or the helper that does that) for your `conversation_id`

2.- Set this id directly on the create method

```
@message.conversation_id = @message.id
```

(is that the behavior you wanted?)

Also, why do you have `@new_message` and `@message`?

#### Update

As said in the comments:

---

I have this

```
<%= link_to "Reply", reply_user_messages_path(@message.sender, :conversation_id => @message) %>   
<%= link_to "Reply", reply_user_messages_path(@message.sender, :conversation_id => @message.conversation_id) %>
```

I need to find a way to merge the two of them. One method sets a conversation_id and the other copies it.

---

#### Easiest way to do that, one line if:

```
<%= link_to "Reply", reply_user_messages_path(@message.sender, conversation_id: @message.conversation_id ? @message.conversation_id : @message.id) %>
```

Comment: I set conversation_id to @message.id for both methods prior to posting here and it left the `conversation_id` column NULL. I tried again to double check and the same result. I went down that road previously and I didn't see the benefit of having a model for Conversations so I scrap it. I have tried a few things so it may not be possible. The end result may be just to revert back to what I had which was it only creates a conversation_id when responding to the original message and the original message id itself will be empty for `conversation_id`. Thanks for taking the time out to assist

Comment: @pwz2000 were you setting it after save? Please post the things you tried so we can help based on that. Maybe a log would help too (some silent validations could cause it).

Comment: Yes I set it on every possible line on the create method. The only way I have been able to set the conversation_id on a new message is by adding to the model  `after_create :set_converstation_id

 def set_conversation_id
   update_column :conversation_id, id 
 end` But that code creates a new conversation_id for every message. BTW ignore @new_message, that is old code.

Comment: @pwz2000 Please post a server log of the transaction and/or the models involved.

Comment: I added the Model where I set the conversation_id on a new message. Just a reminder that I do not want to use this method as it sets a new id for all messages created. The plan is to only create conversation_id for new message, not the replied messages.

Comment: Have you removed the form field for `conversation_id`? That shouldn't be there. Try removing or changing into a hidden field.

Comment: Yes I have removed the form field and also left it hidden. In the view if I have this `<%= link_to "Reply", reply_user_messages_path(@message.sender, :conversation_id => @message) %>` it will set the conversation_id to the current message_id. If I change it to ` <%= link_to "Reply", reply_user_messages_path(@message.sender, :conversation_id => @message.conversation_id) %>` it will keep the current conversation_id if the message you are replying from already has a set conversation_id. I need to find a way to merge the two of them. One method sets a conversation_id and the other copies it.

Comment: `<%= link_to "Reply", reply_user_messages_path(@message.sender, conversation_id: @message.conversation_id ? @message.conversation_id : @message.id) %>`

Comment: It works! Thanks for being so patient with me and taking the time out to help solve this problem.

Comment: If my last comment was what you needed I'll update the answer.